# How to implement parallel binary sort in Java

Tags: java, sorting, parallel-processing

I'm just starting to learn Java and parallel programming. I know how to implement sequential binary sort. But was asked how to parallelize it.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays provide [parallelSort api](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#parallelSort(char%5B%5D,int,int)), since 1.8.

> public static void parallelSort​(char[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex)